# Appending Pandas dataframes row-wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have checked [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) and it should be doing the job, but for some reason I cannot figure out the row-wise append isn't working.

I have two dataframes with size (x,y). I want to combine these two row-wise, so the final dataframe is of size (2x,y).

I have tried to do the following:

```
frame_combined = frame_1.append(frame_2, ignore_header=True)
frame_combined = pd.concat([frame_1, frame_2], axis=1) # also axis=0
```

Edit: Doing these gives me a (2x,2y) dataframe. And also my dataframe has no header.

What am I missing that I get a dataframe that is appended both row and column-wise? And how can I do a simple row-wise append?

Thank you.

Comment: Is possible add some data sample and expected output?

Comment: Try `frame_2.columns = frame_1.columns; df = pd.concat([frame_1, frame_2], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @coldspeed Thank you. It worked. Would you mind explaining what that did and why the usual append would not work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a problem with your `frame_2` headers being different from `frame_1`, this causes a misalignment, and if you're concatenating vertically, then your only option is to assign one to the other.

So do so,

```
frame_2.columns = frame_1.columns
```

Now concatenate:

```
frame_combined = pd.concat([frame_1, frame_2], ignore_index=True)
```